# Selecting the first "n" items with jQuery

Tags: jquery

With Jquery, I need to select just the first "n" items from the page, for example the first 20  links instead of selecting all of them with the usual

```
$("a")
```

Sounds simple but the jQuery manual has no evidence of something like this.

Answer (score 403, accepted):

You probably want to read up on [slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/).  Your code will look something like this:

```
$("a").slice(0,20)
```

Comment: Though the `:lt(20)` approach looks much cleaner, using slice is *much* more efficient if you have a large result set to start with. Unfortunately, when evaluating ":lt" and other positional selectors, **jQuery loops through the entire set**, even if it's just getting the first element. I've written more about this on my blog here: http://spadgos.com/?p=51

Comment: Thank you, a side requirement of my request was about performances, so this the right answer for me.
Thanks to the others for pointing out the :lt selector too.

Comment: Informative comment by @nickf, but the blog link and graph link doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can't edit now sorry -- basically, using slice was a lot faster.

Answer (score 98):

Use lt pseudo selector:

```
$("a:lt(n)")
```

This matches the elements before the nth one (the nth element excluded). Numbering starts from 0.

Comment: [According to the jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/#notes-0), .slice is faster in modern browsers.

Comment: I like the use of jQuery style, it's more elegant, than chaining.

Answer (score 28):

I found this note in the end of the [lt() docs](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/):

> Additional Notes:
>   
>   **Because :lt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :lt() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index) instead.**

So use `$("selector").slice(from, to)` for better performances.

Answer (score 12):

Try the :lt selector: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt#index

```
$('a:lt(20)');
```

Answer (score 7):

.slice() isn't always better. In my case, with jQuery 1.7 in Chrome 36, .slice(0, 20) failed with error:

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I found that :lt(20) worked without error in this case. I had probably tens of thousands of matching elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a:lt(n)")
```

[JQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/)