# jQuery .each question

Tags: jquery, each

Is it possible to run a jQuery .each statement a certain amount of times rather then for each of the items being iterated? The JSON being iterated is a last.fm feed, and of course, they ignore the "limit" request often. I would like to bypass this error by only running the .each statement so many times.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var limit = 5;

$("somelement").each(function(i, val) {
      if(i > limit) return false;
      // do stuff
});
```

or

```
$("somelement:lt(5)").each(function() {
      // do stuff
});
```

Comment: This seems like strong-armed a solution when one already exists in jQuery.

Comment: Actually this works - I was just off by one with the JSON item count. thanks.

Comment: this is not the best solution, you should better use .slice. I added an answer with an example.

Comment: Could you explain how your solution is better than this?

Answer (score 11):

Rather than modify the .each, modify your selector to select only the first 'n' elements.

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt#index

Comment: $("somelement:lt(5)"); will pull back 5 elements

Comment: comment of the accepted answer here suggests that .slice() is much more efficient than :lt(x) and why so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to use the [.slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method in jQuery.

```
var limit = 5;
$("somelement").slice(0, limit).each(function(i, val) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a variable before your loop, increment it within the each, and `if(myvar == 10){return false;}`

> Returning 'false' from within the each
>   function completely stops the loop
>   http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me.  In the accepted answer, "i" would not return an index for me since there was a key.

Answer (score 1):

Return [`false` out of the iterator](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each#objectcallback) when you want to stop. The first parameter to your iterator is the index (when looping through arrays).

Comment: +1 back to you. I would assume some people don't like this solution because it doesn't have the elegance of `slice()` or modifying the selector, but this is an all-uses solution... The true solution when you need to enforce the limit in-loop, maybe after some analysis on whether certain items count towards limit.