# Show first four children with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a `<div>` and in that div there are several `<a>` tags. With jQuery I want to show the first four `<a>` tags.

I have managed that with the following code:

```
$('div.gallery-hor.read-more a:nth-of-type(-1n+4)').show();
```

There's one problem: IE* and later do not support the `:nth-of-type()` code.

Is there a workaround width jQuery to fix this problem cross-browser?

Comment: Have you tried with [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery

Comment: @Dandroid, AFAIK, ie7 doesnt support :nth-child

Answer (score 10):

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt#index

```
$('div.gallery-hor.read-more a:lt(4)').show();
```

Comment: jQuery states `Because :lt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :lt() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index) instead.`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `slice` not just for selecting first four but you can select from any index(start) to any index(end). **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k42ba/2/)**

```
$('div.gallery-hor.read-more a').slice(0,4).show();
```

**[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)**