# Selecting first # of elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="1">bla bla</label>
<br/>
<input id="2" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="2">hello hello</label>
<br/>
.
.
.
etc...
```

Is there a way to select first few inputs here in one call?  In other words, I don't want to select them all and loop through each one.  Just 1 statement to select, for example, first 3.

Comment: Unless you're writing your page in HTML5, IDs should not begin with a number.

Comment: @FelixKling - yes I was aware of that. Comment updated.

Comment: Be sure to select first on a parent div id or something that is more specific than all inputs. Ex: $('#parentDivId input').slice(0, 3) or $('#parentDivId input:lt(3)') both work, as suggested already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery function [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) lets you specify only a subset of the results:

```
$('input').slice(0, 3)
```

Where 0 is the first index and 3 is the *first index not included*, so 2 is the last index and you get the three items.

Comment: Thanks. Works good, chose this answer for the explanation of .slice() function.

Answer (score 4):

Simply select all and slice the result as you need,

```
$('input').slice(0, 3) //will return first 3 input.
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/RhWDY/1/)

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this get all input elements to begin with and then slice off the first three?

Comment: It will return elements starting at index 0 up until but not including index 3: http://dochub.io/#javascript/slice

Comment: @JamieDixon Yes, I believe so. Obviously `$('input')` is not a good way to select inputs if that is what you are concerned about.

Comment: +1 for using slice(). The other suggestions to use the :lt() pseudo-selector are also good, but slice has better performance and does the same thing.

Comment: Also, here's a similar question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
var firstThree = $('#1, #2, #3')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
$("input:lt(3)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
   $('input').filter(function(index) {
       return index < 3;        
    });
```

You can change the `3` to be however many items you want.

Comment: @Vega Well, we've already explored all the practical solutions. ;-)

Comment: @Vega I didn't know about the shorthand selectors (though I bet that's how they're implemented under the hood!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `:gt` and `:lt` selectors:

```
$('input:lt(3)').css('blah, 'blah');
```

This should select the first three input tags on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:lt` selector.

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/