# Can't I filter first 5 elements?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting the first “n” items with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery)

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/MUyJ7/) :

```
<div class="prova">Hello</div>
<div class="prova">Hello</div>
<div class="prova">Hello</div>
<div class="prova">Hello</div>
<div class="prova">Hello</div>
<div class="prova">Hello</div>
<div class="prova">Hello</div>
<div class="prova">Hello</div>
<div class="prova">Hello</div>
<div class="prova">Hello</div>

$('.prova:gt(' + 0 + '):lt(' + 5 + ')').html("Hello Edited");​
```

I'd like to edit the first 5 elements. Why it ignores the first one? (which should be index 0).

Comment: gt = greater than ,  and 0 is not greater than 0 , adjust gt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) instead of [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) or [`:lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) for optimum performance:

```
$('.prova').slice(0,5).html("Hello Edited");​
```

Comment: Can you provide a source to back that up?

Comment: @flem To back up what? I've included links to the three relevant documentation sections.

Comment: I mean the "for optimimum performance"...

Comment: @flem: From the docs: *"Because `:lt()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:lt()` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `$("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index)` instead."* That holds for *all* jQuery selector extensions, so you should avoid them when you can.

Answer (score 3):

if the beginning starts from 0, then just try this:

```
$('.prova:lt(5)').html("Hello Edited");​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MUyJ7/2/

Answer (score 2):

:gt means greater than index of 0 which is the first element. Remove the :gt part of the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `gt`, and since 0 is not greater than 0, it is being excluded. Do something like `$('.prova:lt(5)')`. I don't know why are you doing all these quotation and concatenation stuff.