# appending an incrementing number inside each div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I have a page with multiple div, and I'd like to add an incrementing number inside each div.

I thought this would do the job but it isn't:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i;
    while ( i<count) {
        $('#div').append(i);
        i++;
    }
});
```

I added this script after `</body>`

Comment: do you want an incrementing id?

Comment: @RobinMaben you can smell? great

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention var count=0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
​$("div").each(function(i){
    $(this).append(i);
});​​​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/mcMYG/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $('div').slice(0, count).each(function(i){
       $(this).append(i+1);
    });
});​
```

The `.slice()` is for selecting the first n matched elements (as suggested by `i < count`).
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1865571/448232) for more.

**[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/uVV9X/4/)**

---

**Additionally..**

If your div's(or any element) are siblings to each other you could use the more elegant..

```
$('mySelector').each(function(){ $(this).append($(this).index()) });
```