# How do I select all div's with a div index of less than 6 in jquery?

Tags: jquery, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting the first “n” items with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery)

How do I select all div's with a div index of less than 6 in jquery?

```
$('div.lt(6)')
```

Is this correct?

```
     $('div').slice(0,6).animate({ top:newtop2 }, 700)
    .removeClass("down").addClass("up");
```

I tried this but its not working

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.` instead of `:`, Try the following:

```
$('div:lt(6)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Close, but not quite there. You're using the [lt-selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), so it would be `:lt()` rather than `.lt()` - a `.` in a selector indicates a class. Your code would instead be:

```
$('div:lt(6)')
```

Unless, of course, what you actually want is `<div>` elements where their index *in relation to their siblings*, rather than *in relation to the matched elements*, is less than six.

In which case, I guess you'd need to do something like this:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).index() < 6;
});
```

Comment: I want the div with index less than 6 be animated using top position. I cant get it work

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').slice(0,6)
```

or

```
$('div:lt(6)')
```

Comment: thanks but neither is working for my code    "$('div').slice(0,6).animate({ top:newtop2 }, 700)
         .removeClass("down").addClass("up");"

Comment: This should work. Try something simpler, like `$('div').slice(0,6).toggle()`