# How to put page breaks in xml using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

I have an XML file "data.xml" having details of  around 80 cars  (for each car there is 4 sub nodes). While parsing through Jquery, the entire result is coming in a single page resulting in very large page. The script code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#car').click(function() {
        $.get('data.xml',function(data){
            $('#content').empty();
            $(data).find('car').each(function(){
                var $car = $(this);
                var html = '<div class="data">';                      
                html += '<b>' + $car.attr('company') + '</b>';
                html += '<div class="product">' + $car.find('product').text() + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="color">' + $car.find('color').text() + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="type">' + $car.find('type').text() + '</div>';
                $('#content').append(html);
            });                        
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

What I require is only 8 cars details should appear in that page and the further 8 details in subsequent pages by clicking "GO TO NEXT PAGE".

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest option is to perform an AJAX call for every 8 cars - as you don't want to load too much data in one call.

Nonetheless

- store your XML (or objects) in a place where you can re-use it
- use a counter variable or such, indicating the index of the first-visible item
- create an update-method that shows item n till n+8 (see URL below)
- this function should clear the contents of the #content DIV (as you are using the append method)

[Selecting the first "n" items with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery)

..if you really want to go pro, play around a bit with [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable to define how many records you wish to show in each page, and one that holds which page you're currently on. Then use jQuery's slice() method to choose only the records you want. Then, when your next button is clicked, increment the page number and call your function again. You should probably optimize this to not call reload the XML every time, and add some checking to make sure you don't go past the total number of available records, but you should get the picture.

```
// init your variables
var currentPageIndex = 0;
var recordsPerPage = 8;

function showRecords() {
    // load your xml
    var currentRecordIndex = currentPageIndex * recordsPerPage;
    $(data).find('car').slice(currentRecordIndex, currentRecordIndex + recordsPerPage).each(function(){
        // do your processing 
    });                        
}

$("#next").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    currentPageIndex++;
    showRecords();
});
```