# jquery select html of three paragraphs in a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I select the html of first three `<p>` tags in a `<div>` (or even four). I want to have a function where I could send the number of paragraphs and it would select their html into a variable? any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`lt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/):

```
var t = $('p:lt('+n+')').text();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/gzuvf/

Answer (score 1):

try with [.lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

```
var firstThree = $('div p:lt(3)').html();
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ftpqH/)

Answer (score 0):

Use .slice()

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery).

For example :

```
var = $('p').slice(0,3).text()
```

Or :

```
var = $('p:lt(3)').text()
```

**However, the .slice() function is known as faster with modern browsers**

Comment: **However, we don't use jQuery to get what's fastest.** ;)

Comment: Didn't understand ? You mean there's a faster way to do that without jQuery ? Because, **with jQuery**, I think this is the fastest way.

Comment: can't get $('p').slice(0,3).html() to work. It's ok with $('p').slice(0,3).text() ?

Comment: Look here for working example : http://jsfiddle.net/r9R85/ (Works also with .html())

Comment: if you change second line to <p><br/>two</p> then it does not show it in alert ?