# Jquery limit element query results

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting the first “n” items with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery)

I have an infinite countable list of elements!

Is there a function to find x elements from the head of the list and stop!

```
$('.elements').find('li').limit(10) //this does not work
```

I tried the goog but i could not be specific enough with the ? !

Comment: *"I tried the good but i could not be specific enough with the ? !"* What does this mean?

Comment: `$('.elements').find('li').eq(10)` solves this problem! ref: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can use jQuery's [custom `:lt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) for that.

For instance, this will find only the first three `li`s in the given target list:

```
var firstThree = $("#target li:lt(3)");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/eqafos/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/eqafos/1/edit)

Comment: Though cleaner than @palash's example, this is a lot slower as it needs to use jQuery sizzle engine to comprehend the CSS3 selector. Your bettor off with something like $('#target li').slice(0,3); if performance is a goal.

Comment: @MariusMiliunas: It's not a CSS3 selector, it's a jQuery-only selector. And you're quite right that it relies on Sizzle doing the work and can't be offloaded to the browser. I hadn't seen palaѕн's answer, but I've just upvoted it and encourage you to as well.

Comment: Yep you're right about it being jQuery only.

Answer (score 20):

Try jQuery [slice](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice).  Your code will be something like this:

```
$('.elements').find('li').slice(0,10);
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Marius Miliunas and T.J. Crowder, based on performance, you can just do this:

```
$('.elements li').slice(0,10);
```

Comment: With modern browsers, you're probably better off doing `$(".elements li").slice(0, 10)` so that it's one query selector that can be handed off to the browser, rather than two. +1 for not using jQuery extensions (I'm a bit surprised to see an answer from me that does).

Comment: Just for clearness.. `slice()` IS jQuery extension in above example. Doc: [http://api.jquery.com/slice/](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)