# Limit the jQuery select2 maximum visible (not selected) options

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Limit the jQuery select2 maximum visible (not selected) options

I only want to restrict multi select visible tags options in select2, user can still select more options if they select more options than max-visible number they can see ...

Comment: You can use `:lt(2)`.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005796/jquery-limit-element-query-results

Answer (score 1):

You can use **maximumSelectionLength**

```
   $("#dropdown").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 3
});
```

Comment: It restricts selection as well
I don't want to restrict selection

Answer (score 0):

```
This solved my problem.
I had to restrict the visible selected options which were increasing 
height.
```

[Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jbimmotest/8xn31Ldb/6/)