# How can I select first N elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML:

```html
<div class="notifications_list">
 <div class="title">today <span>+84</span> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </div>
 <ul>
  <li>notification 1</li>
  <li>notification 2</li>
  <li>notification 3</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="title">yesterday <span>-10</span> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </div>
 <ul>
  <li>notification 4</li>
  <li>notification 5</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="title">in last week <span>+32</span> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </div>
 <ul>
  <li>notification 6</li>
  <li>notification 7</li>
  <li>notification 8</li>
  <li>notification 9</li>
  <li>notification 10</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I need to set a background color for first N elements. For example `N = 4`, So I want this:

[image]

As you see, I've set a gray background color to first 4 `<li>` elements. How can I do that by jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting the first "n" items with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery)

Comment: with all these solutions - a single note for all - and the OP. Rather than changing the CSS of the element (in whichever way each solution proposes) - a better solution is to have a class (eg: .highlight{background-color:#ddd} and then using whichever method you choose - add the class to the element - that way you are not altering the elements CSS but adding a class that can be more easily manipulated (eg changing the grey to yellow) or removed. Just my opinion. :)

Comment: @gavgrif thank you for the note.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1174/)

```
$('li:lt(4)').css('background', 'lightblue');
```

Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.

Comment: Just one thing. will this approach work on old browsers like IE7/8 ?

Comment: I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 3):

This will return the first 4 `<li>` elements and set the background color to gray

```
$("li").slice(0,4).css('background-color', 'gray');
```