# Selecting maximum of 10 li items with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to a limit on selections. Let's say for instance a maximum of three. How do I do this? Help would be really much appreciated. Thank you.

```js
$(function(){
var classHighlight = 'highlight'; 

var $thumbs = $('.gallery-item').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

//add the class to the currently clicked element (this)
$(this).toggleClass(classHighlight);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="gallery"><!--one ul is going to wrap all li's -->

<li class="gallery-item">                   
    <figure class="img-wrapper fade">
        <a class="img-box" href="#">
            <img class="center-cropped" alt="gallery image"  src="https://placehold.it/180x180.jpg">
        </a>
    </figure>   
</li>

<li class="gallery-item">
    <figure class="img-wrapper fade">
        <a class="img-box" href="#">                
            <img class="center-cropped" alt="gallery image" src="https://placehold.it/180x270.jpg">
        </a>
    </figure>
</li>

<li class="gallery-item">                   
    <figure class="img-wrapper fade">
        <a class="img-box" href="#">
            <img class="center-cropped" alt="gallery image"  src="https://placehold.it/180x180.jpg">
        </a>
    </figure>   
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you explain what you need exactly ?

Comment: your title says "Maximum of 10", your question says "Maximum of 3"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting the first "n" items with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery)

Comment: You want to limit the selection of "gallery-item" ? try `$('.gallery-item:lt(3)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count how many already have your `classHighlight` and act appropriately

```
var classHighlight = 'highlight'; 

var $thumbs = $('.gallery-item').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // If less than 3 gallery-items have classHighlight
    if($(".gallery-item." + classHighlight).length<3){
        //add the class to the currently clicked element (this)
        $(this).toggleClass(classHighlight);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var li = $( "li" ).slice( 0, 3 )
console.log(li, li.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

You can try with `$.slice(start, end)` more info here https://api.jquery.com/slice/