# How to check 0 to nth index checkbox in using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have checkboxes which I want to check and uncheck by using button

for example suppose I want check checkbox 0 to 9 should be checked then I click on "10 or less" button so other checkbox must uncheck and only that check box checked which index less has than 10

**Button**

```
<button class="1-10">10 or less</button>
<button class="1-25">25 or less</button>
<button class="1-50">50 or less</button>
```

**Checkbox**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="3" /> 3 <br />
          ...
          ...
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="49" /> 49<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="50" /> 50<br />
```

I have used loop for this but may be there is any better way please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting the first "n" items with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `.slice(n, n+1)` to slice out the checkboxes you want. Please see the following question that shares a lot of similarity with yours:

[Selecting the first "n" items with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`jquery filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to *filter* out the checkbox *indices* like this (assuming `n`th checkbox has *value* `n` as in the question):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() >= min && $(this).val() <= max;
}).prop('checked', true);
```

See demo below:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  let min = +$(this).attr('class').replace(/-\d+$/, '');
  let max = +$(this).attr('class').replace(/^\d+-/, '');
  // uncheck all
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
  // check the ones required
  $('input[type=checkbox]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() >= min && $(this).val() <= max;
  }).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="1-10">10 or less</button>
<button class="1-25">25 or less</button>
<button class="1-50">50 or less</button> Checkbox

<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="3" /> 3 <br />

<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="22" /> 22 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="23" /> 23 <br />

<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="49" /> 49<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="50" /> 50<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the relevant element and set their checked property:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.1-10').click(function() {
        $('.age_opts').prop('checked', false);
        $('.age_opts').filter((i) => i < 10).prop('checked', true);
    });
    $('.1-25').click(function() {
        $('.age_opts').prop('checked', false);
        $('.age_opts').filter((i) => i < 25).prop('checked', true);
    });
    $('.1-50').click(function() {
        $('.age_opts').prop('checked', false);
        $('.age_opts').filter((i) => i < 50).prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="1-10">10 or less</button>
<button class="1-25">25 or less</button>
<button class="1-50">50 or less</button>
<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="3" /> 3 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="4" /> 4 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="5" /> 5 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="6" /> 6 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="7" /> 7 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="8" /> 8 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="9" /> 9 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="10" /> 10 <br />
...<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="49" /> 49<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="age_opts" value="50" /> 50<br />
```