# jQuery: fadeIn first n children one by one

Tags: jquery, slice, fadein, children

I am fairly new to jQuery, trying to create a Jekyll theme, which displays first five post elements (paragraphs, titles, images, bullet points) one by one. Now, I’ve got a piece of code that fades in all post elements, which -unfortunately- means that for very long posts, it takes ages to do.

Here’s the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".post-content").children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).delay(300*index).fadeIn(0);
   });
});
```

I read a bit about the `:lt()` selector and `slice()` method but I have not found how to combine one of these with the code above so that only first five children animated this way. I’m probably just missing something stupid?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still want to select the entire group, instead check the index to see if it's less then 5 and only apply `.delay(300*index)` to those. You can make the rest display immediately or how ever else you'd like to, in this example it would load the rest after a 1.5 second delay (*after the 5th one displays*):

```js
$(".post-content").children().each(function(index) {
  if(index < 5)
    $(this).delay(300*index).fadeIn();
  else
    $(this).delay(1500).fadeIn(); //  $(this).fadeIn(); to show immediately 
});
```

```css
.post-content > * { 
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-content">
  <div>foo1</div>
  <div>foo2</div>
  <div>foo3</div>
  <div>foo4</div>
  <div>foo5</div>
  <div>foo6</div>
  <div>foo7</div>
  <div>foo8</div>
  <div>foo9</div>
  <div>foo10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of using if/else, checking the index! Was probably overthinking it for way too long, haha. Thanks so much for your help, Spencer! Your solution works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an working example with the slice, after the promise is only in case you want to display every element after the fades are over, if not just remove it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".post-content").children().slice(0,5).each(function(index) {
      $(this).delay(300*index).fadeIn(0);
   }).promise().then(function( arg1 ) { 
   $(".post-content").children().slice(5).show()
   });
});
```

and about lt and slice difference, here's an answer explaining the difference between them:
[Selecting the first "n" items with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery)

"Though the :lt(20) approach looks much cleaner, using slice is much more efficient if you have a large result set to start with. Unfortunately, when evaluating ":lt" and other positional selectors, jQuery loops through the entire set, even if it's just getting the first element. I've written more about this on my blog here: spadgos.com/?p=51"

Comment: Thanks, sir_ask! I was actually pretty close to what you're suggesting but instead of having is as `.children().slice(0,5).` I had it as `.children(slice(0,5)).` No clue why I did that!