# how can I add classes to all items except the first four

Tags: jquery, element

I want to find in the div with the id CategoryBigContent all elements with the class .interestGrid and hide all elements except the first 4. I have already found the elements, but how can I add hidden only to all classes except the first four and not to all?

```
$('#CategoryBigContent).find('.interestGrid').addClass("hidden");
```

Comment: you are missing a `'` in `$('#CategoryBigContent)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting the first "n" items with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865552/selecting-the-first-n-items-with-jquery)

Comment: You can hide it without JS and using CSS only `#CategoryBigContent .interestGrid:nth-child(4) ~ .interestGrid { display: none; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

John Resig put in so much effort into jQuery so many years ago and nobody seems to appreciate that. ;-)

The problem can be solved by simply using his `:gt()` selector!

```js
$('#CategoryBigContent .interestGrid:gt(3)').addClass("hidden");
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CategoryBigContent">
  <div class="interestGrid">1</div>
  <div class="interestGrid">2</div>
  <div class="interestGrid">3</div>
  <div class="interestGrid">4</div>
  <div class="interestGrid">5</div>
  <div class="interestGrid">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the filter function to filter by index.

```js
$('#CategoryBigContent').find('.interestGrid').filter(function(index){
  return index > 3;
}).addClass("hidden");
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CategoryBigContent">
  <div class="interestGrid">1</div>
  <div class="interestGrid">2</div>
  <div class="interestGrid">3</div>
  <div class="interestGrid">4</div>
  <div class="interestGrid">5</div>
  <div class="interestGrid">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Hello_1234 Have a look at cars10m answer too. I think it's better at least for readability and probably performance wise too.